# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' did not worked out with repair TABLE

Tags: python, mysql

> I am having trouble to execute following code, obviously these statement are part of the code.

```
cursor.execute("select max(propernoun_SRNO) from tblauto_tagged")

starting_index = cursor.fetchone()[0]

if starting_index  == None :

    starting_index = 1

ending_index = int(starting_index) +len(s)

i = 0

for j in range(starting_index,ending_index):
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        c.append(nnp_array_index_coloumn.count(i))
        add1 = add1 + c[i-1]
        add2 = add1 + c[i]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tblauto_tagged(propernoun_SRNO,tagger,train,propernoun,propernoun_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",(j,str(iput),str(corpora),str(nnp_array[add1:add2]),0))
        for item in nnp_array_index_coloumn:
            if item not in uniques:
                uniques.append(item)
                add1=0;add2=0
```

> Error generated is

```
IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.61-community]Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' (1062) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

> I read previous attempts by different user to  to solve the problem but for me nothing  worked out.

```
mysql> repair table  tblauto_tagged;
+--------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------    ------------------------+
| Table                          | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                   |
+--------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| collegedatabase.tblauto_tagged | repair | note     | The storage engine for the table     doesn't support repair |
+--------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> select * from tblauto_tagged;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

> After all of yours helpful suggestion I used following statement

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tblauto_tagged(tagger,train,propernoun,propernoun_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(str(iput),str(corpora),str(nnp_array[add1:add2]),0))
```

> And I ran into another trouble and for sure today is not my day.In order to make my problem more clear, I am editing the question with some additional information. ever thing works fine till propernoun_SRNO =149

```
 mysql> select propernoun_SRNO ,tagger, train,propernoun,propernoun_ID from tblauto_tagged where propernoun_SRNO =149;
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| propernoun_SRNO | tagger | train | propernoun                                                                                                   | propernoun_ID |
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|             149 | 1      | 1     | ['Wing', 'tank', 'Hopper', 'BU', 'crewmember', 'beam', 'injured', 'Drug', 'Serious', 'Marine', 'Incident'] |             0 |
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

> and after propernoun_SRNO = 150 this is what I get.

```
mysql> select propernoun_SRNO ,tagger, train,propernoun,propernoun_ID from tblauto_tagged where propernoun_SRNO =150;
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+
| propernoun_SRNO | tagger | train | propernoun | propernoun_ID |
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+
|             150 | 1      | 1     | []         |             0 |
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> which goes all the way down to propernoun_SRNO =  22201

```
mysql> select max(propernoun_SRNO) from tblauto_tagged;
+----------------------+
| max(propernoun_SRNO) |
+----------------------+
|                22201 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select propernoun_SRNO ,tagger, train,propernoun,propernoun_ID from tblauto_tagged where propernoun_SRNO =22201;
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+
| propernoun_SRNO | tagger | train | propernoun | propernoun_ID |
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+
|           22201 | 1      | 1     | []         |             0 |
+-----------------+--------+-------+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> I don't know what the problem is but I think it needs some experts opinion. As mentioned in the previous comments should I use sequences, please advice

Comment: **NEVER** calculate next PK value manually. Use autoincrement column or sequences instead.

Comment: @zerkems, +1, but there are systems (bad systems, but systems you have to live with) where, for instance, multiple tables all use the same id for their PK instead of doing things the right way with FKs, but aren't always inserted together and in order.  This doesn't look like one of those cases though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain zerkms's comment: You are trying to insert a row with a value for the primary key (`propernoun_SRNO`, if I'm not mistaken) which is already in use.

If you are trying to insert all new rows to the database, don't specify a value for the primary key, and MySQL should calculate one automatically, assuming that the column is set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

If you are trying to replace existing rows with these IDs, use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`, or delete the existing rows before you insert new ones.

Comment: well I tried using the suggestion of zerkms's suggestion it worked but after propernoun_SRNO = 148; there was no record. After record number 148 there were no values at all. I think It is because of my BAD programming techniques; but anyways the comment were very useful in helping me understand the issue. I will try to use sequence as suggested by zerkms.